# find Grand Child of a Element using the parent element

Tags: selenium, protractor, cucumberjs

I have HTML code which looks like this

```
<div class="A"> 
   <div class="B">
       <div class="c">
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

if i do A.element(by.css(.c)) will i be able to get the class c div.

ParentElement.Element(some locator) will it search in grand child of the parent element or only the direct descendants of the parent

if A.element(by.css(.c)) is not the right way which is the correct way to search grand child of a parent element

Comment: You have provided a sample _HTML_, can you update the question with your exact _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the div has a unique class, `element(by.css(".c"));` will find that div. Here is a list of other [locators](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md) you can use. However, you aren't searching for the grand child, you are only finding the element with class "c".
If you are looking to find a grandchild without a class, I would advise using xpath such as `element(by.xpath("div>div>div"));` However, using a unique locator such as an ID or class will always be more reliable.